# Check whether the date changed

Tags: java, swing, date, collections, time

I am working on an attendance project in Java Swing.  Log in should be only once a day.

My project contains of login page which has a database from which user names and passwords are given,  I just want to make sure that login (attendance updated for an employee) takes place only once a day.

How to check whether the date changed?

Comment: *"Log in should be only once a day."*  Am I (as a theoretical employee) supposed to log-out out at lunch time?  What about when I pop outside for a smoke?  ..

Comment: There are way more questions within your question then could possibly be answered. (who's day? What time zone? Employees working multiple shifts, overnight, breaks, etc... What's login got to do with it?  Many more.). Entire *large* systems are built for this purpose.  If you want a simple answer, you're going to need to ask a simpler question - and show some code with what you have tried already.

Answer (score 3):

Does it really matter if someone logs in more than once a day? Actually, your requirement has a spoofing problem.  Suppose that a coworker stole my password, and he used it to log in as me. Then I come in, and I now cannot log in.  It's better to allow users to log in whenever they want, and to show a message "You last logged in at 8:45 AM EDT on 3 June 2013".

If you need this exact requirement, store the last login date in the database as a SQL DATE type, which does not have time-of-day. Have the login code look like

```
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(
    "SELECT last_logon FROM USERS WHERE username = ? AND passwordHash = ?");
// Please don't store the password itself in the database.
ps.setString(1, username);
ps.setString(2, sha1(password, salt)); // very vague, I know.
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
if (rs.next()) {
    java.sql.Date lastLogin = rs.getDate("last_logon");
    // Check that last_logon isn't today.
    // Use an UPDATE to update the field.
}
```

This really isn't Swing-specific, or even Java-specific.  You'll want to look at how your database can compute message hashes, and how you can apply salt to the passwords.  You'll need to decide the salt source.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a Java Calendar, you can also just store last login, then compare to current one:

```
 Calendar lastLogin = // however you set this
 Calendar currentLogin = // now, again, however you set it
 if (currentLogin.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) == lastLogin.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR))
 {
   // it's the same day
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a database table for storing the log data of `login` data and have a columns `userid`, `date` and `login` information. And you can program if `login` value is `0` then the person didn't login otherwise he logged in. If you are clever enough, `login` column is not needed even. Now, if a user tries to log in, check if the record exits in the table against that user for that day.

That's all