# how to know whether date has changed using java?

Tags: java, swing, date, calendar

i am working on office attendance project with simple "login"(where attendance of employee gets incremented on every login,the attendance will be taken once a day, i mean if even  a user logins more than once a day it should be taken as one,so how can i know about the change date??
"what i need exactly is "the user will login twice a day from that we have to receive in time and out time so as to calculate no of working hours in that day? and also to make sure that attendance is incremented just for one day even though he logins multiple times?
visit http://devajkumarsuthapalli.blogspot.in/2013/06/my-java-project.html for code

Comment: Try to be more specific: show the code you have tried, explain why it does not work and you will get better help.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/16898571/1288408

Comment: you can verify is the previous login date and the current date are in the same day `SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
return fmt.format(date1).equals(fmt.format(date2));`

Comment: i was more specfic this time and i attached a link to my question,it was the current status of my project :-/

Comment: @DevajKumarSuthapalli You should edit your original question to make it more specific instead.

Answer (score 0):

Let me help you with a simple design that will help you with further implementation:

You would need to create two database tables: 'Attendance' and 'Users' for tracking information on login and logout. Your schema should look like below:

Attendance

Date         UserId   Login      Logout  PeriodInMinutes

1/6/2013   EMP01   09:00:00  10:00:00   60 

1/6/2013   EMP01   11:00:00  14:00:00   180 

1/6/2013   EMP05   09:00:00  18:00:00   540

User

UserId  Name Address

EMP01   XYZ  Lane20

EMP05   PQR  Lane21

Whenever a user logs-in or logs-out; you would need to insert details in your Attendance table. The User table should be your master table holding user details.

The solution involves querying your attendance table and performing calculations.

For example: If you were to find out whether the user EMP01 was present on June 01, 2013; then query for user EMP01 where date is 01 Jun 2013; if you get results it means the user was present if zero rows are returned, it would indicate that user did not login that day.

Similarly you can also find total hours the user worked on June 01, 2013. Query for user on specific date and sum the column PeriodInMinutes and you will get the total number of minutes. Note that it is your job to calculate time difference between every login and logout. You can insert the time difference in column PeriodInMinutes every time when user logs-out.

The above is just a basic idea. You can further enhance and optimize the case.